# Debugging TeamCity JFrog Artifactory plugin

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, teamcity, artifactory

I have been trying to debug the jfrog artifactory plugin, but i can't.
I downloaded the plugin source, configured my idea for debug connection and connected to `teamcity` (that is running in debug mode), but the execution doesn't stop on breakpoints.

For debugging I used these `jvm` parameters:

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_shmem,server=y,suspend=n,address=javadebug
```

(teamcity is on my local machine )

has somebody else met with such problems?

Comment: How the breakpoints look like when it runs? Got crosses on them?

Comment: No, they absent. It is first what i have noticed.